# How can i match a dynamically changing url in VCR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest, vcr

In my Ruby on Rails application there are 2 Localhost servers running. I am writing test cases for the 1st server and so I have to mock the 2nd server.
For this I am using VCR to record the responses I get from the 2nd server and play the recorded cassette while running the tests on the 1st server.

I am stuck at the part where the 1st server makes a request to 2nd server(**the session_id in the URL changes each time**) and I want the response to be same every time it makes a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VCR you can match requests on any parameters you wish (method, host, path, etc...) using the `match_requests_on` cassette option or a fully custom matcher - https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-3/docs/request-matching

Answer (score 1):

I made this work via params ignoring. So for you something like this could work:

```
VCR.use_cassette('name_of_your_cassette', match_requests_on: [:method, VCR.request_matchers.uri_without_params('session_id')]) do
  # here is your http query
end
```

In my case it was `query` that was changing so I ignored that in vcr request matcher.